# get child element offset position from grandparent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having hard time trying to figure this out. I have a child, parent and grand parent elements. and I want to know the child offset position (position: absolute) in relation to the grandparent HOWEVER this is the tricky part, the parent has to be in position relative as is an accordion so when collapse the child elements collapse as well. I can't leave the parent without position relative other wise the absolute children won't collapse and stay in place.

I currently can get the child position in relation to the parent in Jquery

```
// simple accordion
$('.accordion').on('click',function(){
  $(this).next().slideToggle();
})
// get child offset
var childPos = $('.child').position();
console.log(childPos.top) // top position from granparent
```

CSS

```
.grandparent{
  position:relative;
}
.parent{
  position: relative;
  padding:20px;
}
.child{
 position: absolute
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="grandparent">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="accordion">accordion</div>
    <div class="child">
      child content
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="accordion">accordion</div>
    <div class="child">
      child content
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="accordion">accordion</div>
    <div class="child">
      child content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any help please!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I am understanding correctly, you should be able to repeat your strategy for the position of the parent in the grandparent.

```
var childPos = $('.child').position();
console.log(childPos.top) // top position of child from parent
var parentPos = $('.parent').position();
console.log(parentPos.top) // top position of parent from grandparent
var childGrandparentPosTop = childPos.top + parentPos.top;
console.log(childGrandparentPosTop); // top position of child from grandparent
```

Comment: Can you upvote and mark as the answer?  That would help me out.  Thanks.